# hyperref + redefined headings: "dest doesn't exist..."

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, typography, small-caps

Consider the code below. A key element of that document's typographic style is that the `\section` headings are typeset in all-small caps (= with no capital letters in between). So in order to typeset them properly, TeX needs the corresponding text in all-lowercase. As good TeX users, we insist on strict separation of form and content. We don't want to bother the author of, say, the book, with taking care of this.

Instead we automate this task using a piece of code that converts the argument of a `\section{...}` into lowercase. See the third chunk of code in the example (to be honest, I don't remember where I got it from or how I came up with it).

Everything's fine unless we also decide not to *number* the sections, using the usual `secnumdepth` method.

What happens then is that `hyperref` gets thrown off track.

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{section*.3} has been referenced but does not exist,
 replaced by a fixed one
```

and, in the PDF, the bookmarks and TOC links to the sections stop working.

So the problem seems to be in the interaction between these three things: the lowercase mod, the `secnumdepth` setting, and hyperref.

What would be an appropriate way out of it? I'm assuming one may want to tackle the lowercase mod first, but how?

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,DIV=9]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}

% headings
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\large\itshape}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\scshape}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont}

% lowercase conversion
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{\MakeLowercase{#4}}}%
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
\hskip #2#3\MakeLowercase{#4}}%
\makeatother

% no section numbers
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test I}
\Blindtext
\section{Test 1}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test II}
\Blindtext
\section{Test 2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test III}
\Blindtext
\section{Test 3}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add a `\phantomsection` before `\@hangfrom` to get the correct anchors again

Comment: works great, feel free to add it as answer so I can accept it...

Comment: It's a possible solution, but there's perhaps a better one

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\phantomsection` before `\@hangfrom` restores the correct hyper anchors, which are not preserved apparently.

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,DIV=9]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}


% headings
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\large\itshape}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\scshape}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont}

% lowercase conversion
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
\phantomsection%
\@hangfrom{\hskip #2#3}{\MakeLowercase{#4}}}%
\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
\hskip #2#3\MakeLowercase{#4}}%
\makeatother

% no section numbers
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test I}
\Blindtext
\section{Test 1}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test II}
\Blindtext
\section{Test 2}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Test III}
\Blindtext
\section{Test 3}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```